# class.upload.php and file extension missing

Tags: php

I'm using class.upload.php for images. Resizing works correctly with name and extension into the folder, but i have a problem storing the name into mysql database. There's no file extension (.jpg, .gif etc)... why? how can i resolve the problem?
Thanks

```
     /* ========== SCRIPT UPLOAD MULTI IMAGES  ========== */
     include('class.upload.php');
      $dir_dest="../../images/gallery/";  

    $files = array();
  foreach ($_FILES['fleImage'] as $k => $l) {
    foreach ($l as $i => $v) {
        if (!array_key_exists($i, $files))
            $files[$i] = array();
        $files[$i][$k] = $v;
    }
}

foreach ($files as $file) {

    $handle = new Upload($file);
      if ($handle->uploaded) {

    $mainame = $handle->file_dst_name;

    $db_name = str_replace(" ","_",$mainame);
    $image1 = md5(rand() * time()) . ".$db_name";
    $parts = explode(".",$image1);
    $extension = end($parts);
    $result_big = str_replace("." . $extension,"",$image1);

         $handle->file_new_name_body   =  $result_big;
         $handle->image_resize     = true;
         $handle->image_x          = 460;
         $handle->image_ratio_y    = true;
        // $handle->image_y          = 400;
         $handle->Process($dir_dest);

        //Thumbnail
     $db_name = str_replace(" ","_",$mainame);
     $image1 = md5(rand() * time()) . ".$db_name";
     $parts = explode(".",$image1);
     $extension = end($parts);
     $result_small = str_replace("." . $extension,"",$image1);    

         $handle->file_new_name_body   =    $result_small;
         $handle->image_resize     = true;
         $handle->image_x          = 180;
         $handle->image_ratio_y = true;
        // $handle->image_y          = 120;
         $handle->Process($dir_dest);

         // we check if everything went OK
        if ($handle->processed) {
              header("Location: index.php");    //echo 'image resized';
               $handle->clean();

    $query_img="INSERT into tbl_images (file_name, pd_image, pd_thumbnail) VALUES('$nome','$result_big', '$result_small')";      
       $result2 = dbQuery($query_img);

  } else {
      echo 'error : ' . $handle->error;
  }
    }
     }
// END SCRIPT UPLOAD MULTI IMAGES

 header("Location: index.php"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have replaced the extention with empty string here using `str_replace`

```
$result_small = str_replace("." . $extension,"",$image1);
```

and here

```
$result_big = str_replace("." . $extension,"",$image1);
```

update below lines just add `.$extension` at the end

```
$handle->file_new_name_body   =  $result_big.$extension;
```

and

```
 $handle->file_new_name_body   =    $result_small.$extension;
```

**just change query like this**

```
$query_img="INSERT into tbl_images ( 
                file_name, 
                pd_image, 
                pd_thumbnail
             ) VALUES (
               '$nome',
               '{$result_big}.{$extension}', 
               '{$result_small}.{$extension}')";
```

I will suggest you to have same filename for `pd_image` and `pd_thumbnail`, just prefix thumb with `thumb_` that will make your life easier in front end.

this way you can access any image thumbnail just by prefixing it with `thumb_` with `pd_image` and you don't have to store `pd_thumbnail` in database.

Comment: It doesn't work in this way. I have a double dot on folder file ( example: file..jpg) and only a dot into the DB ( example: file.)

Comment: Works for image name on folder, but on DB i have only a dot after the name

Comment: have you used updated query, check your db tables `pd_image` and `pd_thumbnail` length, make it 50 VARCHAR

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64045/discussion-between-ogum-and-saqueib).

Answer (score 0):

You are removing the extension with this code
$result_big = str_replace("." . $extension,"",$image1);

I dont know why you do that. anyway you can add it back by adding following line after the $handle->file_new_name_body   =  $result_big;

$handle->file_new_name_ext = $extension;

Comment: $result_big = $image1;
  
             $handle->file_new_name_body   =  $result_big;
             $handle->file_new_name_ext = $extension;
it works, but i don't understand why i can't see the image into the folder. it's without extension, but on web page i can see the image

Comment: You mean once the $handle->Process() runs it will only create a file without an extension? for eg: if you upload abc.png it will create a file only with abc?
btw try this too, $handle->image_convert = 'jpg'; this is only to debug the issue. 
normally when you upload a file with class.upload.php it creates the file with same name and extension. can you past a image url?

Comment: yes it create a file only with the name..but i can see it on front-end! sorry but i'm working on localhost